# can not rename remote file using sharpssh

Tags: rename, sftp, sharpssh

i wrote like the following code.
but this code is not available...

when i execute, occur.
if anyone knows something, give me advice pls...
thanks in advance.

---

```
void sftp_OnTransferEnd(string src, string dst, int transferredBytes
                          , int totalBytes, string message)
{

    if (sftp == null)
{
sftp = new Sftp(Const.SFTP_HOST, Const.SFTP_USER, Const.SFTP_PASSWORD);

sftp.Connect();

}

SftpChannel.rename("file/123_Uploading.zip", "file/123_Finished.zip");
}


--------------------------------------------
Sftp.cs

public void Rename(string oldPath, string newPath)
{

   SftpChannel.rename(oldPath, newPath);

}

---------------------------------------------
```

Error occur the following place...

```
---------------------------------------------------------
ChannelSftp.cs

public void rename(String oldpath, String newpath)
{

・

・

・


int i=buf.getInt(); << i == 4

if(i==SSH_FX_OK) return;

throwStatusError(buf, i); << throw error

catch(Exception e)

{

if(e is SftpException) throw (SftpException)e; << thrown error (id >> 4, message >> Failure)

throw new SftpException(SSH_FX_FAILURE, "");

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The current NuGet package is still of version `1.1.1.13` which does not contain the `Rename` method. It would be great if the package maintainer could update it.

But in the meantime if anyone else needs it with the current NuGet package, here is a Reflection-based extension method solution. Not nice, but at least I can use the package without forking/rebuilding, etc.

```
public static void Rename(this Sftp client, string oldName, string newName) {
  var channelProperty = client.GetType().GetProperty("SftpChannel", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
  channelProperty.GetValue(_client, null).CastTo<ChannelSftp>().rename(OldName, newName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added your

```
public void Rename(string oldPath, string newPath)
{

   SftpChannel.rename(oldPath, newPath);

}
```

code into Sftp.cs class and I called it :

```
  var sftp = new Sftp("sftp.example.com", username, password);
  sftp.Connect(22);
  sftp.Rename(oldValue, newValue);
  sftp.Close();
```

then it renamed my file successfully.Thanks by the way

Comment: I bubbled up the rename method from SftpChannel to Sftp as well -> http://bitbucket.org/mattgwagner/sharpssh